# How do you run a specific migration for DataMapper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datamapper

With dm-migrations, how can I migrate to a specific version?

Answer (score 3):

Are you using Datamapper with Rails? If so, try

```
rake db:migrate:up[version]
```

to go up or

```
rake db:migrate:down[version]
```

to go down. For exemple, if you want to migrate up to version 3, just type

```
rake db:migrate:up[3]
```